# Substituting text that overlaps

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

I have a piece of data (**data.txt**) that, due to user fault, looks like that:

```
4,48
4485
4,49
4495
4,5
4505
4,51
 4,6
11445
11,45
```

The pattern is this: whenever there is a comma, 0s have been dropped. So: 4450 was improperly changed to 4,45, 4600 was changed to 4,6; and 11450 changed to 11,45.

So, two actions should be performed when a comma is found:

1. Add one or two 0 on the right, to get three digits right of the comma:
   d,dd ->  d,dd0 ; or d,d -> d,d00
2. Delete the comma
   ddd0 ; dd00

The end result should be:

```
4480
4485
4490
4495
4500
4505
4510
4600
11445
11450
```

How could I use a regex on **sed** (or another program) to get this result?

1. One solution would involve splitting the data in two files, dataa.txt and datab.txt:

dataa.txt:

```
4,48
4485
4,49
4495
4,5
4505
4,51
 4,6
11445
11,45
```

and datab.txt:

```
4,5
4,6
```

For the first file:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\,[0-9][0-9])/\10/g;s/\,//g' dataa.txt
```

and for the second file:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\,[0-9])/\100/g;s/\,//g' datab.txt
```

Then, concatenate the files. It would be better to do that without these extra steps (spliting and concatenating).

2. There are very good solutions using **awk** (thank you!), and one is reproduced below:

   $ awk '{gsub(/,/, ""); printf "%.4s\n", $0 * 1000}' data.txt

But when dealing with 5 digit numbers (you can spot them for the number of digits on the left of the comma) it also does not work. It would also would require spliting the data.

How could we achieve the end result, without splitting the data?

**(edited for clarity)**

Comment: The questions is getting longer as you think of things which isn't good for us reading it. Please tidy up your question to just explain your needs and show 1 [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers both your 4-digit and 5-digit cases. Make sure to state how we can tell if numbers like `4,5` and `4,05` are supposed to be output as 4-digit `4500` and `4050` or 5-digit `45000` and `40500`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have enough digits after the comma. Next cut everything after the third decimal and remove the comma:

```
sed -r 's/(,.*)/\1000/; s/,(...).*/\1/ ' data.txt
```

Note: the `\1000` is remembering matched string 1 with `\1` and adding `000`.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

If current row contains `,` multiply its value with 1000.

```
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '/,/{$0=$0*1000} {print}' file
```

or shorter

```
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '/,/{$0*=1000}1' file
```

Output:

```
4480
4485
4490
4495
4500
4505
4510
4600
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '{gsub(/,/, ""); printf "%.4s\n", $0 * 1000}' ip.txt
4480
4485
4490
4495
4500
4505
4510
4600
```

- `gsub(/,/, "")` remove all comma characters
- `$0 * 1000` multiply the number with `1000`
- `printf "%.4s\n"` print only first four digits

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'split($1,d,/,/)>1 { $0=sprintf("%-*d",length(d[1])+3,d[1]d[2]); gsub(/ /,0) } 1' file
4480
4485
4490
4495
4500
4505
4510
4600
11445
11450
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve using a regex: it was missing the anchor ´$´. The single line of code of **sed**:

```
sed -E 's/(\,[0-9]$)/\10/g;s/(\,[0-9][0-9])/\10/g;s/\,//g' data.txt
```

Previously, I was using `\,[0-9]`, that is ambiguous with this data, and matches both **4,5** and **4,51**. The regex `\,[0-9]$` matches **only 4,5**, not 4,55. To match **4,51** we can use `\,[0-9][0-9]`.

Thanks for the **awk** solutions, very elegant and using a different approach.